# Overwriting keychain generic password with SecKeychainAddGenericPassword

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keychain

My application saves a database password in the preferences window. When preferences are saved, I use `SecKeychainAddGenericPassword`. Of course this only works the first try; subsequent calls return `errSecDuplicateItem`.

Is there a convenient `SecKeychainSetGenericPassword`?

The next simplest solution is to delete the existing password before I set mine. Is there any harm in doing that?

This seems like it would be a very common scenario; some sample code would be appreciated.